# What is the Escape character for SQL snippet file

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I am writing a SQL Snippet in VS2010 and I want to have "$" as a character inside the SQL Snippet, but the way the snippet recognize a variable is by bounding a word with "$". EX: $var1$

Anybody know what the escape character is for SQL Snippet in VS2010, so it won't think of it as a variable by mistake?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to escape it by doubling it - try `$$`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$$` (from here: http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2006/08/visual-studio-2005-snippets-literal.html).